# Problem with production download option in Android things Console

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I'm developing an Android Things application for the company that I work for, the problem is in the Android Things Console, because I upload the signed apk for release but when I create the image there is only developer version of that image, we need a production image of the app (because the app after 1 day close and only show the configuration screen)

here a few images of our problem

[image: photo3]

[image: photo1]

[image: photo2]

[image: photo4]

```
<activity
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising this issue. This is an error in the documentation and we will get it corrected. Production images are not available for Raspberry Pi 3.

> I upload the signed apk for release but when I create the image there is only developer version of that image, we need a production image of the app (because the app after 1 day close and only show the configuration screen)

This is not related to the image type you download or how you sign the APK. It's more likely because the system isn't recognizing your app as the `HOME` app, so it returns to the system UI after a crash. When you boot your device with the app installed, do you see it or the system UI?

I would recommend cleaning up your manifest entry to match the [home activity example](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0#home-activity-support) in the docs. The `HOME` and `LAUNCHER` categories should be in separate filters (because they won't be found together) and `IOT_LAUNCHER` is not longer used.

Comment: Thank you very much, i’m going to check thai And ley you know soon as posible if this solution works!